# Passing string into an event listener function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to copy some text to a clipboard upon clicking a button. Currently, its working when I have a separate function to copy different sections of the HTML that I want to copy, however when I write 1 function for both with a parameter it doesn't work.

I have 2 functions which look like this

```
function copyStringToClipboardA () {
  // Create new element
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  // Set value (string to be copied)
  el.value = document.getElementById("trackEvent").value;
  // Set non-editable to avoid focus and move outside of view
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  el.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  // Select text inside element
  el.select();
  // Copy text to clipboard
  document.execCommand('copy');
  // Remove temporary element
  document.body.removeChild(el);
}

function copyStringToClipboardB() {
  // Create new element
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  // Set value (string to be copied)
  el.value = document.getElementById("identifyEvent").value;
  // Set non-editable to avoid focus and move outside of view
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  el.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  // Select text inside element
  el.select();
  // Copy text to clipboard
  document.execCommand('copy');
  // Remove temporary element
  document.body.removeChild(el);
}
```

The only thing that is different in those 2 functions is `el.value`

I call these 2 functions on a button click which looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
//Event Examples
    var b = document.getElementById('trackCopy');
    var c = document.getElementById('identifyCopy');

    b.addEventListener('click', copyStringToClipboardA, false);
    c.addEventListener('click', copyStringToClipboardB, false)
});
```

I am trying to write 1 function that takes a string as a parameter instead of writing 2 functions.
I tried writing the following function which takes a string as a parameter:

```
function copyStringToClipboard(myInput) {
  // Create new element
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  // Set value (string to be copied)
  el.value = document.getElementById(myInput).value;
  // Set non-editable to avoid focus and move outside of view
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  el.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  // Select text inside element
  el.select();
  // Copy text to clipboard
  document.execCommand('copy');
  // Remove temporary element
  document.body.removeChild(el);
}
```

and then I call it on click like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
//Event Examples
    var b = document.getElementById('trackCopy');
    var c = document.getElementById('identifyCopy');

    b.addEventListener('click', copyStringToClipboard("trackEvent"), false);
    c.addEventListener('click', copyStringToClipboard("identifyEvent"), false)    
});
```

The issue I have with this implementation is that the second one `identifyEvent` is copied every time.

The behavior I want to achieve is copying the selected text into the clipboard.

Comment: It seems that you're looking for [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)

Comment: Just curious: Why don't you place `getElementById` and `addEventListener` calls into the function too? since they are obviously identical too.

Comment: `copyStringToClipboardA`, what you passed to addEventListener originally, was a function _reference_, now you substituted it for a function _call_, `copyStringToClipboard("trackEvent")`. Go read up on how those are two fundamentally different things first of all, https://stackoverflow.com/q/14568291/10955263

Comment: You’re gonna need an anonymous wrapper function around those `copyStringToClipboardA` calls here.

Comment: `, () => copyStringToClipboard("trackEvent")`, ditto for the other one.

Comment: Thank you all, that was good reading. @wOxxOm your suggestion did the trick, thank you very much. I'll go ahead and scrap this mess thou, it needs to be built from the ground up a better way. Thanks again all <3